# Fragment's onCreateView doesn't save member reference

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, otto

I have a `MainActivity` with a `ViewPager`. The `ViewPager` consists of two `Fragments` each holding a single `RecyclerView`. I need to have a reference to the `RecyclerView` for updating/animating it etc. in the `Fragment`.

A problem occurs on screen rotation, because for some reason I cannot set the member variable back to the `RecyclerView`.

```
public abstract class NotifListFragment extends Fragment {

    protected RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    public NotifListFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
        EventBusHelper.getBus().register(this);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notif_list, container, false);
        setupRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);


        return mRecyclerView;
    }
```

So here in the `onCreateView` I always inflate the fragment and save the reference in `mRecyclerView` variable. However, when I later try to access it, it is null.

I am using [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) to call both `Fragment`'s `onDataChanged()` method. It is called when a button in the `RecyclerView` is pressed.

```
@Subscribe
public void onDataChanged(DataChangedEvent event) {
        List<CustomNotification> oldData = ((NotifRecyclerViewAdapter) mRecyclerView.getAdapter()).getmValues();
        List<CustomNotification> newData = getNotifications();
}
```

The `mRecyclerView.getAdapter()` is null in this call.

Fragment's `getView()` also returns null. What is happening?

Comment: What do you mean "when I later try to access it"?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: How are you sure that onDataChanged is called after onCreateView?

Comment: I am logging every time the onCreateView() is called. I rotate the screen, in the log I can see onCreateView() is called and mRecyclerView is not null. Then I click a button in the app. At that point it crashes with mRecyclerView suddenly set to null.

Comment: Okay, my bad. I should also unregister when onDestroyView() is called, because it seems that with every rotation there are two more Fragments registered to receive the messages, along the old ones. And the old ones don't have any layout anymore, so they throw errors. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that I found wrong here. Please don't call `setupRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);` in your `onCreateView()`, this is something that should be called on your `activityCreated()` because your fragment might not have been attached to your activity till then. Plus I don't like to do `findViewByIds` there.

Use the [`onViewCreated()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated(android.view.View,%20android.os.Bundle)) and [`onActivityCreated()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)) callbacks.
So your code would look something like this.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notif_list, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mRecycler = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.yourId);
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setupRecyclerView(mRecycler);
}
```

It's possible that during your call to `onDataChanged()` that the fragment might not have been added. Do a null check there.